# Rails Activermerchant and Trustcommerce Vault BillingID question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, credit-card, activemerchant, e-commerce

I am building a rails app using the wonderful activemerchant gem to save credit card information in Trustcommerce Citadel for future transaction. I am currently able to send in hash of billing address and credit card information to save in Citadel, but I am kind of puzzled as to how I might retrieve the BillingID that is generated and saved in Citadel for future use. That is, I want to retrieve the BillingID to save in my own database so that the user is able to locate his/her information in the future. Has anybody had experience with this? Thanks

Comment: authorize() method returns "transid", but I am wondering if store() returns "billingid". Does store() method not return anything? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

store() method returns "billingid" from Trustcommerce Vault for retrieval. use params['billingid'] to retrieve the id.